# Expand VBA code to multiple shapes

Tags: vbscript, colors, fill

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("E9")
If IsNumeric(cell) Then
    If cell.Value < 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Hi, how can I expand this code to work with multiple shapes? I tried to just copy everything from Set cell to End if and changed up the Set cell value and shape but this didn't work.

Comment: What you described should work fine. Changing the `cell` (which is a terrible variable name since it's `cell` is already and object type in the excel library) and changing the name of the `ActiveSheet.Shapes("namehere")` is the right way to go to target another cell/shape combination Perhaps your cell value isn't numeric when you think it is? Also `activesheet` is not a great choice. `Sheets("yoursheetname").Shapes("yourshapename")` would be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim x As Range
Set x = Range("E9")
If IsNumeric(x) Then
    If x.Value < 0 Then
        Sheets("DIA").Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    Else
        Sheets("DIA").Shapes("Rectangle 2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    End If
End If

Dim y As Range
Set y = Range("T9")
If IsNumeric(y) Then
    If y.Value < 0 Then
        Sheets("DIA").Shapes("Rectangle 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    Else
        Sheets("DIA").Shapes("Rectangle 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

This works, any smarter ways?